# TaffyDB merge example

Tags: taffydb

I am using TAFFY for the first time.
I want to insert new data to my column which already contains some data, 
I want to append my new data to the column.
How to do it , is it possible to do this with db.merge() ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use .update(), can't you?

```
var info = TAFFY([
  {id:1, name:"John Smith"}, 
  {id:2, name:"Matt Anderson"}
]);

info({id:1}).update({name:"Jane Smith"});
```

If you want to use merge, just replace the last line with something like this:

```
info.merge({id:1, name:"Jane Smith"}, "id", false);
```

If you want to try it on your own computer, must create a file called `test.html` on your desktop. Download `taffy.js` onto your desktop also.

**Test.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="taffy.js"></script>
        <script>

        var info = TAFFY([
          {id:1, name:"John Smith"}, 
          {id:2, name:"Matt Anderson"}
        ]);

        //info({id:1}).update({name:"Jane Smith"});
        info.merge({id:1, name:"Jane Smith"}, "id", false);

        alert(info({id:1}).first().name);

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>

</html>
```

In your browser, open test.html. You should see Jane Smith appear in an alert window. If you comment out info.update or info.merge, John Smith will appear.

EDIT: In order to append 'Stany' to whatever name there is in id:1, you could do:

```
var changedName = info({id:1}).first().name + ' Stany';
info.merge({id:1, name:changedName}, "id", false);
```

instead of

```
info.merge({id:1, name:"Jane Smith"}, "id", false);
```

Comment: What if I want to add another value in name . like :

id : 1,name:"Jane Smith Stany"

How to add stany to the column name ?
Thank you for your response

Comment: `info.merge({id:1, name:"Jane Smith Stany"}, "id", false);` or `info({id:1}).update({name:"Jane Smith Stany"});` should do it. Is that what you were trying to ask?

Comment: No, Here You are providing the previous data to the name column (for merge).
I don't want to give previous data I just want to append 'stany' to the name column to the existing values Jane Smith.
I am not bothered what is there in name, I just want each time I get a name It  should append to the name column.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @ShivkumarMallesappa - does this answer help or are you looking for something else?

Comment: Thank you very much sir.